# Private method in custom resource does not work

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I would like to do similar thing using Custom Resource:
Here is provider code (LWRP) which works

```
action :create
  my_private_method(a)
  my_private_method(b)
end

private
def my_private_method(p)
  (some code)
end
```

If I make similar code using Custom Resource, and define private method, chef-client run fails with error:

```
No resource or method 'my_private_method' for 'LWRP resource ...
```

What is the syntax to declare/invoke private method in Custom Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_resource.send(:my_private_method, a)`, and because of this making things private isn't hugely recommended.

Comment: Thanks,Really ugly. In ordinary LWRP it is regular method call.

Comment: It would be the same in a normal LWRP, but remember you are defining the method on the resource class, not the provider.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: this is the preferred way now:

```
action :create do
  my_action_helper
end

action_class do
  def my_action_helper
  end
end
```

These alternatives both work:

```
action :create do
  my_action_helper
end

action_class.class_eval do
  def my_action_helper
  end
end
```

and:

```
action :create do
  my_action_helper
end

action_class.send(:define_method, :my_action_helper) do
end
```

in the latter case if you have args or a block on your method its the standard define_method syntax, examples:

```
# two args
action_class.send(:define_method, :my_action_helper) do |arg1, arg2|
# varargs and block
action_class.send(:define_method, :my_action_helper) do |*args, &block|
```

we probably need some DSL sugar added to the custom resources API to make this nicer.

(added ticket for this issue: https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4292)